# Is possible to have 2 child threads with different classpath in each one?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, classpath, conflict

I have a "core" application that is adapter to process task. Each task is implemented in an adapter load by the core to process the task.

My question is, is it possible to have different classpath in each adapter to precent class/jar conflict between adapters.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed:

```
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Thread thread = new MyThread();
thread.setContextClassLoader(cl);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassloader()` and make a new `URLClassLoader` with the desired classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. using Thread's setContextClassLoader method.

check following link(little old but useful) for understanding it better:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-06/01-qa-0606-load.html