# Reverse classload order on a Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to reverse the classloading path on a single Java thread where the java application is ran standalone.

Ie All other threads operate correctly and search the classpath front to back, whilst a single thread will search the classpath back to front.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible to have 2 child threads with different classpath in each one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522332/is-possible-to-have-2-child-threads-with-different-classpath-in-each-one)

Comment: What is you goal ? Why do you want to reverse the classloading path order ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual use case? Why that thread alone needs to look up in reverse order?

You can try creating your own customer class loader to do the look up in reverse order from the class path and set that class loader as the context class loader for that thread using the thread.setContextClassLoader(..) api. Then explicitly use that context classloader to load the classes or any other resources.

But couple of caveats:

1) Generally the classloaders are parent first..Which means, when u create a custom class loader u will be setting parent class loader (generally system class loader unless u have used any other custom loaders in your application). Else u will not be able to load the java.* classes which can only be loaded by bootstrap loader, which is the root. As per rule u should delegate a class loading request to parent first and only if not found, then load yourself. So when u try parent, it will anyway look up in the original order and load the class. So for this to work, u will have to break that rule. Instead of delegating to parent first, u will have to look up in reverse in your classloader and only if not found, should delegate to parent class loader to load it

2) If parent class loader has already loaded the class, ur class loader may again load it. That means, the classes loaded in this thread will be considered as a separate instance.

Never tried this, but in theory this should work...but all practical purpose, this may not be useful for the reason mentioned in (2).

These links will be useful:[link1](http://njbartlett.name/2012/10/23/dreaded-thread-context-classloader.html) [link2](http://www.techdarwinia.com/java-classloader-and-context-classloader) [link3](http://kalanir.blogspot.in/2010/01/how-to-write-custom-class-loader-to.html)

Another way is, just change your system class loader and when u load/find class, look up in whichever order you want based on the current thread name.

Both approaches are weird, but the requirement is such that :-)